# Website crashes after some time after starting with error EADDRINUSE for port 80

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ubuntu

### ISSUE

I have created a react based website which works on node-express server.

I have my backend server running on port 3000 which runs fine but the website running on port 80 doesn't.

When I start my website (https://www.edvicer.com) using pm2 as `pm2 start server.js`, after some time (an hour or two), the website crashes and I get the following error in pm2 logs which means the port 80 is already in use:

```
errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 80
```

This has happened a number of times.

I have tried rebooting and syncing the server. I have used screen (`screen -r`) to start the server.js and I have tried starting it using `node server.js &` but all the time, the same thing happens.

### The main code for server.js is:

```
[const httpsOptions= {
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ssl', 'cert1.crt'), 'utf8'),
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ssl', 'cert1.key'), 'utf8'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ssl', 'intermediate.crt'), 'utf8')
}

var redirectToHTTPS = require('express-http-to-https').redirectToHTTPS;

app.use(redirectToHTTPS(\[/localhost:(\d{4})/\], \[/\/insecure/\], 301));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'));
});
  http.createServer(app).listen(80);
  https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(443);][1]
```

### Errors

After I start the website and when it is working fine, I saw the ports used:

### netstat -tulpn | grep :80

Using netstat -tulpn | grep :80, I get something like:

```
tcp  0  0  :::80  :::*  LISTEN  2465/node /home/erd
```

When I do netstat -tulpn | grep :80 after website crashes, I get 2 responses:

```
tcp  0  0  127.0.0.1:80  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  16145/httpd

tcp  0  0  :::80         :::*       LISTEN  16145/httpd
```

### ps -ef

Similarly, I tried ps -ef, before the website crashes, I get:

```
UID    PID    PPID    CMD

root   2465   3291    node /home/erdsmsmy/public_html/edvicer/server.js
```

After the website crashes, I get many responses as:

```
UID      PID      PPID      CMD

root     16145    1         /usr/sbin/httpd -k start

nobody   16146    16145     /usr/sbin/httpd -k start

nobody   16148    16145     /usr/sbin/httpd -k start

nobody   16149    16145     /usr/sbin/httpd -k start

nobody   16150    16145     /usr/sbin/httpd -k start

nobody   16151    16145     /usr/sbin/httpd -k start

nobody   16152    16145     /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
```

I can't understand what is happening. Please help.

Comment: You cannot bind on ports below 1000 without using sudo. Second, is the website actually available over port 443? httpd means apache is installed, either use apache as reverse proxy for your node app or uninstall it and it's associated startup scripts.

Comment: Thank you. The website was available over port 443 but yes, apache was obstructing the port. I uninstalled apache and httpd is not creating any problem anymore. Problem solved! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache was obstructing the path for the server. I uninstalled Apache as I am using an Express-based server so I don't need Apache and httpd stopped creating problem.